# In order to complete the highway on time, the workers worked _____ quickly _____ there was not even a time to talk.?

Tags: sentence-construction

In order to complete the highway on time, the workers worked _____ quickly _____ there was not even a time to talk.

options given:

(a)such, that (b)as,as (c)such, as (d)so,that

My Approach

Ans d because i found it the most appropriate.

Any better approach to analyze the Ans? or Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try this backwards:

- **such** needs a noun - but in your sentence you need something to describe an adverb, *quickly*, thus (a) and (c) can't be correct.
- **as - as** is used in comparisons to express equality between two semantically similar things - this is not the case here (counter-example: "*they worked as quickly as they could"), ruling (b) out.
- **so - that** - the *so* is for adverbs  what *such* is for nouns (see above), *that* gives a causal connection between the two sentences.

-> Answer (d) is correct